# Head & Shoulders and Bullflag Rectangle patterns

Tags: trading

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SELauVQ1Tk

The above video describe several pattern with high degree of success. I would like to implement two of them, i.e. Bullflag Rectangle pattern and the Head & Shoulders pattern. I tried to implement it using the scanners from Trade-Ideas, but they do not work at all. Is there an alternative to implement them? Do you have another website which could allow me to target them quickly?

Comment: "Do not work at all" is not diagnosable. The patterns may be bogus and just have happened to work for one person at one time, your implementation may be wrong, ... Requests for recommendations of other websites are generally considered out of scope here, I'm afraid.

Comment: All technical analysis (trading patterns) is bullshit.

Comment: Well, I was trying not to say that.

Answer (score 5):

All technical analysis (trading patterns) is bullshit. None of it works, and you should not expect it to work. It is no better than [numerology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology).

As a general rule, there are no patterns in the stock market. None. Because, if there was a pattern, a large trading company which has people smarter than you and hired computer servers in the stock exchange basement would be able to make money from doing the opposite of the pattern, and they would keep doing this (making money and cancelling out the pattern) until the pattern was completely gone. This is called the "Efficient Market Hypothesis".

Mostly, people who tell you about these patterns are trying to sell you books or video courses. Selling bullshit lessons about the stock market to suckers *is* a reliable way to make money using the stock market.

Comment: People really don't like hearing that the only ""system" that works reliably is to invest rather than trade.... or to be a broker taking a commission on other people's trades whether they win or lose ... or to spend the megabucks in both computing power and minimizing transmission time to take advantage of microsecond arbitrage windows (And I'm still not convinced that's reliable enough to justify the effort.)

Comment: BTw, there's apparently a "quant" area of Stack Exchange where you might find more of the people who do believe they can find a way to reliably beat the system.

Comment: Technical analysis uses geometry and pattern recognition. Quantitative finance uses mathematical analysis, probability and statistics. I doubt many people in quant finance have ever looked at technical analysis. After all, most pricing / analysis in quant finance relies random walks.

Comment: @keshlam You can absolutely "trade". You have to place bets based on not the market itself, but on things you think will affect the market in the future, that you think aren't reflected in the price yet. Last year I thought Tesla was way too high so I made a couple thousand with Tesla put options. Now I think the consumer is going to get squeezed and the S&P 500 is still way too high taking that into account, so I lost that same money on S&P put options. (Which doesn't mean it was a bad bet - losing sometimes is just the nature of gambling)

Comment: Ah. Wasn't sure where the line was between technical and quant.

Comment: If you want to gamble, you can gamble. But remember that you are paying the house on every transaction, so like a casino you are starting in a statistically losing position. And the dealers just _love_ people who think they have a system.

Comment: But at least you're gambling on a belief that's based on your reading of what things should be worth, not in the shape of the data.

Comment: @keshlam yes, that is how "investing" works too. So-called "investing" is mostly just betting that the economy will continue making more and more money, which is perhaps an unjustifiable assumption

Comment: Less so. Investing in the market as a whole (diversified rather than trying to pick specific winners and losers) is betting with the house rather than against it. All I'm betting is that the economy continues to operate and for the most part makes a profit, which is not certain but is pretty likely over longer time scales. I'll take winning relatively consistently for near zero effort over low probability of a bigger win with more effort. There is a difference, though the brokers and publishers may argue otherwise.

Comment: @keshlam the market is not the house, your broker is the house. (also, if you sell options then you are also the house and if you buy options, the seller is the house)

Comment: Your broker takes the commission, but is closer to being the dealer than the house; they don't set the odds on the game. The stock exchange as a whole comes closer to being the house, but it has a designed-in bias toward being profitable because that's what let's businesses use stock to raise capital when needed and because overall business makes a profit. Betting with that bias is, effectively, betting with the house. You are certainly welcome to disagree, but the very existence of "market rate of return" seems to support my view.

Comment: It is far easier to reliably get market rate of return, or something close to it, than to beat that rate. And you can do it with low-fee index funds, which drastically cuts brokerage fees -- and those fees, as percentage of transaction, subtract directly from your effective APR and eat part of the improvement you're hoping to get by trading.

Comment: @keshlam Indeed. That's betting on market rate of return being positive. It's also easy to get any other rate of return (e.g. the Treasury yield, or the rate of growth of Microsoft stock) and then you are betting on that being positive, too.

Comment: Bet yes. Gamble, as I use the word, no.Trading is gambling, unless you invest a _lot_ of time and effort in understanding exactly what you are doing and why, and I remain unconvinced that it is worth that investment unless you go whole hog and make it a profession... and even the professionals have questionable results, which is why college endowment funds don't only invest in the stock market..

Comment: @keshlam betting is gambling

Comment: We agree that we disagree.